# Exchange Server Global Events

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm looking to mirror contacts added to exchange in a separate system. I'd like to do this as contacts are added if possible.

I've seen some listeners available in the API I can use, but those look like they're on a user basis. To use them I think I'd have to have an instance open for every user and I believe they also only remain open for 30 minutes.

Is there anyway to get a notification whenever any user adds a contact to exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no such thing as global events in Exchange (not since 2007 anyway) the closest would be Transport agents but these are only useful for items that are traversing the Transport Pipeline. The application your developing will need to deal with things on a Mailbox by Mailbox basis.

Cheers
Glen